# How can I spellcheck entire website?

Tags: web-development, testing

I need to spellcheck an entire website(950 pages).  I'd like to find a FREE tool like xenu (which checks broken links) but checks spelling instead.

does anyone know of a tool like this?

Thank you

note: i've seen a few free services online that ask for the web address and the email the results to you but they limit you to checking only a few pages....I have 950.

Answer (score 3):

If you're running Linux, you might consider the following process:

1. Download the site recursively with `wget -r http://site.com/`
2. Parse out all of the HTML tags with `find ./ -name \*.html -exec sed 's/<[^>]\*>//g' {} > /var/tmp/all_words.txt \;`
3. Spellcheck the result with `spell /var/tmp/all_words.txt` (note that in-page Javascript and CSS declarations may be included here - use `egrep` to filter undesired words)
4. Review the "misspelled words" list and find/replace in the original directory structure as appropriate
5. Upload revised static content back to site

Answer (score 2):

Download a free trial of any web editor ;)

E. g. Dreamweaver or Microsoft Expression Web

Comment: Just note that these programs have limited ability to check dynamic websites which they cannot fully preview. For static ones though, this is the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The spellchecker I created and support is HTML Validator Pro. There are an average of 175 typographic errors per webpage checked by this tool. Of all the on-page metrics, spell checking uses so much CPU it's not funny. 950 pages is a tall order for free and to process in-one-go!

But if you can feed your website to us in digestible pieces, then it might be possible. Provide each sub folder of your site to our tool and it can be done up to 50 pages without email address, 75 pages with. You can also add any domain-specific words to your own dictionary. Up to this point is completely free